# iPhone/iOS: How can I get a list of localized strings in all the languages my app is localized in?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, nslocalizedstring

I need to send my server a list of localizations for a particular string.

Meaning, if my app has a string Foo which is localized as @"Foo" in English and @"Фу" in Russian, I'd like to send the server a list such as this:

- String Foo:

  - English: "Foo"
  - Russian: "Фу"

What I think I need to be able to do is:

1. Enumerate localized strings for each language my app is localized for
2. Get the localized version of Foo for each language

How do I do (1) and how do I do (2)?

Comment: Have you peeked at `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle

Comment: From table seems to be a way to compartmentalize your strings, as opposed to keeping them all in one default table. This is not what I want. I want to get all the different localizations of a particular string.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can retrieve all of the string keys by reading in English.lproj/Localizable.strings as a dictionary and fetching its keys:

```
NSString *stringsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:stringsPath];
```

To get each language's translation, you can iterate over the languages for each English key and use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`:

```
for (NSString *language in [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]) {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]];
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", language, NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Testing", @"Localizable", bundle, nil));
}
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable; the other options I saw required rewriting the way we retrieve strings, but this is way less invasive and looks like it does what I need. I'll try it today.

Comment: Note that the first call to `pathForResource` in the code samples above will return the path for the *current* localisation, not necessarily the english one (e.g. if your simulator/device is set to german, you will get the path to `de.lproj/Localizable.strings`).