# Is it possible to get the key's from Localizable.strings?

Tags: iphone, localization, xamarin.ios, localizable.strings

I got the values for the key's when I passing the corresponding key. But now I need to get the key's from `Localizable.strings` file. Is it possible with MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this thread. It's in Objective-C but it should be pretty easy to translate to C#. [iPhone/iOS: How can I get a list of localized strings in all the languages my app is localized in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310487/iphone-ios-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-localized-strings-in-all-the-languages-my-ap)