# Extract values from keys in localizable.strings file in iOS

Tags: ios, excel, localizable.strings

I have 12 localisable.string files in my xcode project. Here is the format

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings(English)

"HELLO" = "Hello!";


/* 
  Localizable.strings(German)

"HELLO" = "Hallo!";
```

Now what I want to achieve is this

Extract only the values from the keys in a file and create a excel sheet so the excel sheet should be like this below

```
(English)   (German)

Hello       Hallo
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310487/iphone-ios-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-localized-strings-in-all-the-languages-my-ap + CSV to export to Excel?

Comment: Use Xcode to create the XLIFF files for all your localisations, and then use one of the XLIFF to Excel translator plug ins.